# Ajax AntiForgery won't validate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

A lovely attribute...

```
public class GlobalAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
            {
                var token = request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    AntiForgery.Validate();
                }
                else
                {
                    var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                    var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie == null
                        ? null
                        : antiForgeryCookie.Value;

                    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, token);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Angular $http post...

```
$http.post('', this.data, {
                headers: {
                    '__RequestVerificationToken':
                        $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers) {
                    console.log(data);
            });
```

Then in the HTML..

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

The cookie value in the browser is there as expected as is the value of the hidden field, but they don't validate.

Why not?

Comment: Doesn't the AntiForgeryToken get posted in the body rather than the header?

Comment: Normally yes, but when posting JSON with an Ajax request this appears to be the common alternative.

Comment: @Jasen I was being an idiot again... The action had the built in AntiForgery attribute applied to it in addition to my custom version.